# Java Multithreading - Volatile Boolean not working?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

so I have 3 threads that will try to find a randomly generated number (each thread has its own range which is startNum and finishNum).If one of them stops because it's found the number, I want all the other ones to stop as well.

I've read about a "volatile" boolean which apparently is a boolean that ALL the threads share so that it's always 1 value.

This is the code I have: (note: it's okay if a thread ends while the others are on-going if the thread "stopped" because its startNumber went over its finishNumber)

```
private volatile boolean numberFound = false;

public void run()
{
    while(startNum < finishNum) //what i'm talking about with the [note]
    {   
        search( startNum); 
        if(numberFound == true)
        {
            break;
        }       
    }   
}  
private synchronized void search(int startNum)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if( startNum != searchNum )
        {
            startNum++;
        }
        else if(startNum == searchNum )
        {
            numberFound = true;
            System.out.println( this.currentThread().getName() + " has found the number: " + searchNum );
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

Oh also, I have it looping 10 times each because I want the program to check the number 10 times each in each range of number (thread) and move onto another.

Here is the main() method that starts the thread as requested:
     int randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * 1001);

```
    FindIt t1 = new FindIt(randomNum, 0, 349); //FindIt extends Thread
    FindIt t2 = new FindIt(randomNum, 350, 699);
    FindIt t3 = new FindIt(randomNum, 700, 1000);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
```

Comment: Just for the record, you don't have to test for `numberFound == true`. Just `numberFound` works quite fine. :)

Comment: Please please please PLEASE do not start your questions with "so". Every time I see a question which starts with "so" it makes me weep for the English language. At least use "So"!!! But even that will make me cringe.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. May the grammar god come kill me tonight in my sleep T.T

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your three threads could be in different instances of this class and therefore would have 3 different booleans

Try making the boolean static and see if it changes anything.

(I can't really help you more because I don't see the code that starts the threads)

Note: Volatile doesn't actually mean that all threads share it, it means that IF all threads share it then a change in one thread will reflect in the same variable in other threads.  It's needed because with multi-CPU machines with independent caches it's possible that one thread updates it's version and another doesn't pick up the change because it already has that memory cached....

Comment: I'll upload the main() method :)

Comment: Yeah, add the static modifier to numberFound and it should work fine.

Comment: I've tried making it static just now, and it didn't seem to help. When I run, it doesn't end and doesn't display anything.

Comment: It looks like you are assuming startNum and searchNum as though they were shared too.  Try making them static as well.

Comment: Oh I found the problem. It was because I was doing: search( startNum) and the method void search( int startNum)...
I got rid of the parameter and it works just fine O_O (with the static)

Comment: I don't understand why though.. I took it out saying "I don't really need to have that there do I?"
And that apparently was the problem O_O (cuz I've tried doing static before you mentioned it to me)

Answer (score 1):

The answers that mention that `numberFound` must be `static` are correct.  And the struff about locking with `synchronized` is also correct (though it is not clear that you *need* to lock here ...).

But it is another bug that has nothing to do with concurrency that is causing your immediate problem.

```
while(startNum < finishNum) {   
    search(startNum); 
    if(numberFound == true)
    {
        break;
    }       
}

private synchronized void search(int startNum) {
    ... 
    if (startNum != searchNum) {
        startNum++;
    }
    ...
```

The problem is that the `startNum` you are incrementing is not the same `startNum` you are testing in the `while` loop.  In Java, arguments are passed by value.  So what is happening is:

1. You are passing the value of `startNum` in the `run` method to the `search` method.
2. The `search` method puts that in a local variable.
3. The `search` method updates the local variable.
4. The `search` method returns, and the updated local variable is started.
5. Back in the `run` method, the value of `startNum` has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

numberFound is not declared as static therefore each thread will have it's own property value set independently. 
The same with synchronized method- each thread will obtain a lock on itself so actually synchronising search method like that is probably not what you want. can you explain better why you have this method synchronized?
here is more about volatile: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml

and more about synchronization and locking:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

I recommend having a separate object that would be a shared resource between all the threads - having such approach default locking would be executed on the shared object itself so therefored threads would start 'fighting' for a lock on the object.

Comment: The reason I have it synchronized is because I need 1 thread to check for the random number 10 times, and yield so that another thread can check 10 times.

Comment: so then I guess you should have this method externalized to a shared resources (object) or make it static. I would go for option one.

Comment: Can you expend on what you mean in your option 1?

Comment: I would have a new object of a new class that have numberFound property. It could have search synchronized method. You would create it before instantiating threads. You then would pass it in to each thread so that each thread could set it's private property (ie. sharedNumberFound )  with the object you created beforehand. Having done so all threads would reference to the same shared object.